# Ffmpeg: add a short audio at the end of a mp4 video

Tags: ffmpeg

What would be the command to add a short audio at the end of a video mp4?

Let's say the overlay audio lasts 3 sec. My video last 26 min.

At 25:50 min (video duration - 10 sec) the overlay audio starts. The original audio of the video is silenced for 3 sec meanwhile the overlay audio runs. Then the original video sound comes back after 3 sec.

Comment: Can you add what you already tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basic syntax is

```
ffmpeg -i video -i audio \
       -filter_complex "[0]volume=0:enable='between(t,1550,1553)'[v];\
                        [1]adelay=1550000|1550000,apad[a];\
                        [v][a]amix=duration=first:dropout_transition=0,volume=2[mix]"
       -map 0:v -map '[mix]' -c:v copy output
```

Comment: ffmpeg -i 1533448450120.mp4 -i wat.mp3 -filter_complex "[0]volume=0:enable='between(t,2550,2553)'[v];[1]adelay=2550000|2550000,apad[a];[v][a]amix=duration=first:dropout_transition=0,volume=2[mix]" -map 0:v -map '[mix]' -c:v copy output.mp4 . <br /> I have this error do you know why? [mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 00000259219a2620] Invalid stream specifier: '[mix]'.
    Last message repeated 7 times
Stream map ''[mix]'' matches no streams.
To ignore this, add a trailing '?' to the map.

Comment: You may need to use `-map "[mix]"`

Comment: command starts but it doesn't put my watermark. https://mega.nz/#!Cf4UTIqT!NjNXqTUqh7eS8KFQsBy8pTVHPvxsIQ1aIhv30xLsjnY I upload the example here could you see where is the problem? Thanks

Comment: Nice watermarking works great. Now how can I make the video silent when the audio watermark runs? I have uploaded a new example where the watermark audio is longer (27sec).  https://mega.nz/#!CThxnYSC!mXWczJpWwenKBbImtunfjtuHvVNilu3KAD2AdSrG0RU  Currently both audios are mixed, would be great to listen only the watermark. Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: The video will be silent as long as the timings in the volume filter is correct. The time is stated in seconds.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178731/discussion-between-user3409988-and-gyan).